# When condition on eloquent with the column values on the table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

How can I add in conditional the value of the query i'm using on when function of eloquent laravel?

**Here's what I want to happen**

```
$user = User::when('logged' == '3', function ($q){
        $q->where('role', 'admin');
        )}->get();
```

As you can see I want to get the role admin only when the column `logged` is equal to 3 how can I do this one ? thank you.

**P.S.**

just an example query. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not how [when](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Concerns/BuildsQueries.html#method_when) works,
the first condition `'logged' == '3'` will always return `false`;

So it will not use the closure query, directly use `get()` method, and return all the User's records;

You need to do it like this:

```php
$user = User::where(function($q) {
    $q->where(['logged' => 3, 'role' => 'admin'])
})->orWhere('logged', '!=', 3)->get();
```

Comment: that's not what I want to do tho. I only want to add the `where('role', 'admin')` if the `logged == 3` not both of them is where

Comment: @Jovs logged is the column of users table?

Comment: both `role` and `logged` is column of users table. I only want to put the where if the logged is equal to 3

Comment: @Jovs so do you want to get if logged = 3 will return admin, and other logged value will return all role? I have posted, is that what u expecting?

Comment: This could work on my current problem. But I still want to use the `when` function because in the future I need to add also a non column value to the conditional. do you have solution for that? thanks

Comment: @Jovs if you want to use non column value to the conditional, you can still use `when` and then your column value condition can be closure inside the when method.

Comment: I need to use them as `&&` example `when('logged' == '3' && !empty($status)`

Comment: that will be something like this: `User::when($status, function($q) {$q->where(function($query) { $query->where(['logged' => 3,'role'=>'admin']); })->orWhere('logged','!=',3);})->orWhere('logged', '!=', 3)`

Comment: why two orwhere? anyway I solved it. Thanks I will accept this answer that gave me the idea.

Comment: @Jovs u're welcome. The first `orWhere` is for `!empty($status)` but `logged != 3`, the second is just `$status` is empty

Comment: Oh. I solved it using orwhere too but inside of where function.

Answer (score 0):

You may only want to apply a where statement if a given input value is present on the incoming request. In short you first condition is not base on your table field but base on the request you have.  So @TsaiKoga answer's is correct.

The when method only executes the given Closure when the first parameter is true. If the first parameter is false, the Closure will not be executed.

Please read docs here [when](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#conditional-clauses)

Comment: I know the when method only executes the given closure when the first parameter is true. that's why that's what I'm using. I also gonna put a not column on that when condition in the future.